# Assigning a Texture2D to an existing Texture2D

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d

I am currently messing with C# XNA 4.0, but I am having some problems assigning a Texture2D to an existing Texture2D.
An example of the code shown below:

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        texDisc48 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("textures/disc_24");
        texDisc48 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("textures/disc_48");
        texDisc96 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("textures/disc_96");
    } 
// Random place in the code
texCurrentDisc = texDisc96;
```

But when I am trying to use the texCurrentDisc in etc Draw, I get the following error:
**This method does not accept null for this parameter.
Parameter name: texture**. 
The texCurrentDisc is just initalized as: **Texture2D texCurrentDisc;**

Comment: Are you sure you are assigning it correctly at correct time? Is there reference to same texture in texCurrentDisc when you call Draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simply a mistake in the code, with the texture got initialized too late, before it should draw it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you load the texture using "textures/disc_96"? I thought it had to use something like "textures\disc_96".  Also you assign to texDisc48 twice.
So maybe try:

```
    texDisc24 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("textures\\disc_24");
    texDisc48 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("textures\\disc_48");
    texDisc96 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("textures\\disc_96");
```